# Parse Http Request Batch Text and Convert it to Object and Properties Using C#

Tags: c#, parsing, httprequest, batch-request

I have the following HttpeRequest Body as Text:

```
--batch_f1d4b121-35c3-40a0-bbbd-cb1a9f1a5f13
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

POST /api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5102
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"value": "Hello World"}
--batch_f1d4b121-35c3-40a0-bbbd-cb1a9f1a5f13
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

PUT /api/values/5 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5102
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"value": "Hello World"}
--batch_f1d4b121-35c3-40a0-bbbd-cb1a9f1a5f13
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

DELETE /api/values/5 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5102


--batch_f1d4b121-35c3-40a0-bbbd-cb1a9f1a5f13--
```

I tired using regex and I succeed in some and fail in others.

Dose any one manage to parse and split ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could use MultipartSection to navigate through the batch requests:

```
                    var boundry = request.GetMultipartBoundary();
                    var contentTypeBoundry = request.ContentTypeBoundary();
                    var requests = new List<HttpRequestMessage>();

                    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundry, request.Body);
                    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();                                    
                    while (section!= null)
                    {
                        var xBodyAsText= await new StreamReader(section.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                        requests.Add(xBodyAsText.ToSimpleHttpRequestMessage());
                       
                        section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                    }
```

I have got a solution from ChatGPT:

```
public static HttpRequestMessage ToSimpleHttpRequestMessage(this string text)
        {
            var lines = text.Split("\r\n");
            var requestLine = lines[0].Split(' ');
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://" + lines[1].Split(": ")[1] + requestLine[1]);
            request.Method = new HttpMethod(requestLine[0]);
            if(lines.Length > 4)
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(lines[4], Encoding.UTF8, lines[2].Split(": ")[1].Split("; ")[0]);
            }
            return request;
        }
```

I need better if any one faced something like it.